# Is it possible to convert a cURL request to a VBA winHttpRequest?

Tags: excel, ms-access, curl, vba

I have the request below, trying to get a paypal auth token to retrieve a transaction list from my account.

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
 -u "client_id:secret" \
 -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

And I have gone this far:

```
Set objHTTP = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
sURL = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
objHTTP.Open "POST", sURL, False
'what should go here? is the POST request correct? Are -H in cURL for headers?
objHTTP.send (sBody)
```

Can you help me get this working? Is there maybe an easier way to have the cURL requests "converted"?

EDIT:

```
sURL = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
objHTTP.Open "POST", sURL, False
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
User = "user"
Password = "password"
objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(User + ":" + Password)
```

Runtime Error 5

Invalid procedure call or arguement. Any ideas?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384060

Comment: That seems to be JS or C++. The JS code does seem a bit similar to what I use with the objHTTP, but that link still doesnt explain much.

Comment: It's the same object; you use it the same way.  That's how you set a header.

Comment: Headers are the H? what about -u and -d?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example. I don't run Excel anymore so I can't get at the code but it's in there, just open the macro editor. This uses the MSXML library to do an XHR fetch from a REST API.

https://rack.pub/cdn/miles.xlam

Comment: He's running in VBA, not a browser.

Comment: OK, just trying to help. Like I said I'm not sure if the MSXML library enforces CORS or not. VBA alone don't support XHR, you've got to add a reference to that MSXML library AFAIK.

Comment: VBA cannot possibly enforce SOP; it doesn't have an origin.

Comment: fair enough. XHR in VBA is well documented. should be easy to do then.

Comment: any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/ It works. I havenot done it ina while. I was using it to pull in distances in miles from Googles Maps API.

Comment: assuming -h is headers and -u is user credentials, what is -d?

Comment: objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(User + ":" + Password)
Failing at this step.

Comment: Here's a working example. preciate an accepted answer. good luck. https://rack.pub/cdn/miles.xlam

Comment: That is nothing close to what I asked. No headers on that code, no authentication etc.

Comment: read your API's doc. you can use `window.btoa` in a browser to put your auth stuff in there. Sure VBA has something similar. Best of luck.